# Apply styles in Windows.Resource from another ResourceDictionary XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, resourcedictionary

I need some help with my XAML code.
I have this code. I use the style from the references in each TextBox control, that works perfectly.

```
xmlns:estilos="clr-namespace:Application.UtilityApplicationLayer.Recursos;assembly=UtilityApplicationLayer"

<TextBox x:Name="Name" Style="{estilos:ApplicationWindowsResource ResourceKey=WaterMarkTextBox}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="Middle name" Style="{estilos:ApplicationWindowsResource ResourceKey=WaterMarkTextBox}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="Last name" Style="{estilos:ApplicationWindowsResource ResourceKey=WaterMarkTextBox}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="Age" Style="{estilos:ApplicationWindowsResource ResourceKey=WaterMarkTextBox}"/>
```

Now I want to do is to create the TextBox controls without directly apply the style in each one. I have done this, but that doesn't work.
Any suggestions.

```
xmlns:estilos="clr-namespace:Application.UtilityApplicationLayer.Recursos;assembly=UtilityApplicationLayer"

<Window.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
<Setter Property="Style" Value="{estilos:PractalisVentanasRecursos ResourceKey=WaterMarkTextBox}"/>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox x:Name="Name" />
<TextBox x:Name="Middle name"/>
<TextBox x:Name="Last name" />
<TextBox x:Name="Age"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the ResourcesDictionary that lives in estilos UtilityApplicationLayer? I means the full resource Dictionary Xaml code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use Styles looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{estilos:PractalisVentanasRecursos ResourceKey=WaterMarkTextBox}"/>
```